# Cannot execute shell command with subprocess.Popen

Tags: python, linux, shell

When i try to execute a command with subprocess.Popen. I am getting this error;

```
In [3]: subprocess.Popen(["su - dhclient","eth0"])
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
OSError                                   Traceback (most recent call last)
/home/oae/<ipython-input-3-1cd768a39571> in <module>()
----> 1 subprocess.Popen(["su - dhclient","eth0"])

/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.pyc in __init__(self, args, bufsize, executable, stdin, stdout, stderr, preexec_fn, close_fds, shell, cwd, env, universal_newlines, startupinfo, creationflags)
    677                             p2cread, p2cwrite,
    678                             c2pread, c2pwrite,
--> 679                             errread, errwrite)
    680 
    681         if mswindows:

/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.pyc in _execute_child(self, args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds, cwd, env, universal_newlines, startupinfo, creationflags, shell, p2cread, p2cwrite, c2pread, c2pwrite, errread, errwrite)
   1247                     if fd is not None:
   1248                         os.close(fd)
-> 1249                 raise child_exception
   1250 
   1251 

OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

How can i fix this? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
subprocess.Popen("su - dhclient eth0", shell=True)
```

Comment: `shell=True` is generally frowned upon as a security issue so don't over use it.  It is, however, the correct way to do it in this case.